# How does one associate Visual Studio subscriptions with a company Azure subscription?

Tags: visual-studio, azure, subscription, azure-application-insights

I have a Visual Studio subscription.

I'm trying to implement Application Insights in a Web API application in Visual Studio.

The wizard is trying to associate AI with my Visual Studio subscription.  Rather, I want to integrate with my company's Azure subscription.

So, how is this done?  Do I have to contact the Azure admin and add me to Azure?  I have seen responses like "add you as a co-administrator".  This is pretty dumb, when you're a developer.

Our company Azure subscription has Active Directory integration.  So what.  How do I register with the company Azure subscription that I want to implement services as a developer in the company??

Can someone provide some insight or references?  The documentation is ponderous on this point.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you need to [obtain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-create-new-resource) an `Instrumentation Key` from a resource that is created in your company's Azure portal. Then, you can install application insights in your project and use that instrumentation key.

If, on the other hand you are asking why you have to be a co-administrator then you are correct. This [was the case](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/2853349-provide-role-based-access-to-the-azure-management) for a while but not anymore. 
Account admin can now assign new users to specific resource groups. Each resource group can contain one or multiple resources. Read more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-configure

Comment: i wish it were just an "instrumentation key".  Try installing application insights into an application in visual studio.  it will immediately ask for an Azure subscription.  Of course, if you work at a company, you want to use the company's Azure subscription, NOT your own.  The documentation fails to explain how enterprise teams integrate developers!?  If i'm a solo developer i get it.  but, there's a few extra hoops on the enterprise side....